MPD can't output audio
I installed MPD on Ubuntu 24.04. MPD has started and is contacting the client.
When I try play I get message: Failed to enable "My Pulse Output" [pulse]: pa_context_connect() has failed: Connection refused
My audio_output in mpd.conf:
audio_output {
type        "pulse"
name        "My Pulse Output"
}
mixer_type "software"
When no audio_output section in mpd.conf MPD recognized JACK audio type but I had message: "{setvol} No mixer" or similar.
